# zedgraph axis label font size

Tags: .net, zedgraph

I'm using zedgraph to display a graph, but it need to be a small graph. my problem is the font of the axis labels and axis name is so small that it cant be read.

I'll appreciate any help.

Regards,
Amichai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple code:

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GraphPane myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;

        myPane.YAxis.Title.FontSpec.Size = 10.0f * (this.Size.Width / 100);

        zedGraphControl1.Refresh();
    }
```

---

[image]

Comment: You can set the `font size` according to your requirements..!

Answer (score 1):

To set the axis label font size I used:

myPane.YAxis.Scale.FontSpec.Size

in the same way as San mentioned for title font size.